# Android tablet app send receive data from usb

Tags: android, usb, tablet

I want to build an app for my android tablet that will receive and send data to two usb devices on different ports. Before I start I'd like to know if such thing is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely possible.
I'm currently developing on a Toshiba Thrive for a USB data acquisition device, and I can route through a USB hub to access multiple devices.

You should make sure you are developing on a device that supports USB host mode (the galaxy is known to have usb issues, while the Toshiba Thrive does quite well with a full size USB type A port). I'd also recommend running honeycomb at least, ICS and JB are better. Yes, I know the API has been backported, but again, users have reported issues.